# Why exactly does the determinant of a square matrix have to be zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

In every standard linear algebra class, it's said that in order to solve the generalized eigenvalue problem for square-matrices $A$ and $M$ with elements over $\mathbb{C}$,

$$(A-\lambda M)\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$$

the determinant of the matrix $(A-\lambda M)$ must be zero. The standard proof goes by showing that in order for the equation to be true, you must be able to solve for the elements via matrix manipulation, and this involves dividing by the determinant, which then allows more than one solution other than the trivial one. I don't really like this. Surely there's a better way to show this, but I can't find a really good one.

Could you give me a different proof (or hint at one) for why the determinant must be zero in order for there to be non-trivial solutions to this equation?

For example, one that I thought of is this (though I don't know if it's true):

Set $(A-\lambda M)=\Omega$, and suppose it has a non-zero determinant. This means that the inverse $\Omega^{-1}$ exists. The equation can then be rewritten as

$$\mathbf{x}=\Omega^{-1}\Omega\mathbf{x}=\Omega^{-1}\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{0}$$

So the only solution is the trivial one, which is a contradiction.

Comment: If $x$ is a non-zero vector, then the matrix $(A-\lambda M)$ cannot have full rank, so its determinant must be zero.

Comment: Rename:  $B = A - \lambda M$.  Then, the generalized eigenvectors $\mathbf{x}$ are solutions to the equation $B\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$.  If you want nonzero vectors, then you want nontrivial solutions to the equation.

Comment: @Arturo Don Juan: Your proof is entirely correct, and it is probably the simplest proof possible.

Comment: There is a huge list of conditions that are equivalent to the determinant of a matrix being zero.  Which of these conditions are you familiar with?  If you list those conditions then we can probably show how $(A - \lambda M)x = 0$ for nonzero $x$ implies that one of those conditions holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need the fact that if the columns(rows) of a square matrix are linearly dependent, if and only if the determinant is not zero. this leads to the fact that determinant is zero if and only if $Ax = 0$ has non trivial solution. it is the last fact that gets used to determine the characteristic values $\lambda$ of $A$ by the equation  $det(A - \lambda I) = 0$ and the existence of $u \neq 0, (A - \lambda I) = 0.$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there exists a non-zero solution to $(A-\lambda M)x=0$. Then that means that $A-\lambda M$ is not one-to-one (as $(A-\lambda M)0 =0 = (A-\lambda M)x$ but $x \not = 0$), thus $A - \lambda M$ is not invertible and hence $A- \lambda M$ has determinant $0$.

Comment: This is definitely great, though the only thing I don't like is how you end with *... and hence $A-\lambda M$ has determinant 0*. It's obviously correct, but just a bit too "up front", if you get what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

Use the comatrix of $\Omega$, i.e. the matrix of cofactors of $\Omega$: if $\Omega \mathbf x= \mathbf 0$, then $\operatorname{com}(\Omega)\cdot\Omega\mathbf x=\mathbf 0$.

However,  $\operatorname{com}(\Omega)\cdot\Omega =(\det \Omega)\, I$, hence $(\det \Omega)\, I\mathbf x=(\det \Omega)\,\mathbf x=\mathbf 0$.

So either $\mathbf x=\mathbf 0$ or $\,\det \Omega\,=0$.